# IE is not accepting more than 270 characters of Email body

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, internet-explorer, webforms

I am supporting an old web-forms aspx application. Application should trigger an email popup on client side which contains a template so that user can add/edit information. I am having issue here, when template contains more than 270 characters email popup is not coming in IE browser and it is fine in chrome. I have looked in various forums to see mail to body character limit for IE and no where I can see it is limited to 270 characters. I am pasting some code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <div <%= authUserGroup? "":"style=\"display:none\"" %> <%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Petition)Container.DataItem).Session) ? "style=\"background: red;\"" : "" %>>
                <a href="PetitionEdit.aspx?PetitionId=<%# Eval("PetitionId") %>&Filter=<%= Filter %>">Edit</a> 
                <a href="Output.aspx?Type=Petition&PetitionId=<%# Eval("PetitionId") %>&Format=Word">Print</a>
                <a href="<%# EmailPetition(CropString(Eval("Member").ToString(),55), "P" + Eval("PetitionId", "{0:000000}"), Eval("Presented", "{0:d}"), CropString(Eval("ShortTitle").ToString(),55)) %>" onclick="return btntest_onclick(<%# Eval("PetitionId").ToString() %>)">Email</a>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                    OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");'
                    Text="Delete" />

            </div>
             <div <%= authUserGroup? "style=\"display:none\"":null %>>
                <a href="PetitionView.aspx?PetitionId=<%# Eval("PetitionId").ToString() %>">View Details</a>
            </div>


            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan oops!! I for got to  update. updated now

Comment: can you please share the rendered HTML too?